# Referencing framework and static library in SPM

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have this request of incorporating a static library into the existing SPM module, since this is a third-party library, I have no way to convert this to xcframework to make it work. I am curious if anyone has stumbled across this issue and how have they incorporated this? Just want to update that this is a module of a library not an app to reference it within the app, hence the compilations in utilizing this.